# Advanced histogram usage in Python with numpy

Tags: python, numpy

I need to quickly do this across large amounts of data, so I ideally want to use an approach such as numpy that is fast. I would normally just write a loop but python is too slow for that. Here is the problem:

I would like to add up sums according to the bins of another array. for example, i have three arrays of

```
weights = [100, 130, 112, 150]
ages = [1, 14, 15, 25]
```

I want to sum the weights according to ages being binned with bins of 0-9, 10-19, 20-29. so i'd get [100, 130+112, 150] -> [100, 242, 150] as my end result.

My current understanding of [numpy's histograms](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.histogram.html) is that I would only be able to sum the array that I am binning with. Meaning that I could only get the sum of the ages if I bin ages.

I would also like the knowledge of how to do this well, it's likely in the future other operations than sums will be required of me (such as averaging them rather than just a pure sum). Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done pretty simply with a list comprehension and some numpy logical functions, and it won't be limited only to summation.

```
import numpy as np

ages = [1, 14, 15, 25]
weights = np.array([100, 130, 112, 150])  # easier indexing with a np.array
bin_left_marks = np.arange(0, 40, 10)
my_func = np.sum
my_binned_aggregation = [my_func(weights[np.where(np.logical_and(bin_left_marks[i] <= ages, ages < bin_left_marks[i+1]))]) for i in range(len(bin_left_marks) - 1)]
```

Basically, for each bin, find the indexes of the ages list that match that bin, and aggregate the weights list accordingly.
Good luck!

---

Obviously can be done "less ugly" by splitting that one-liner, using a straight-forward loop, etc. This solution is going for concise.

Comment: Thanks for the help. Was worried I wouldn't get a question due to the negative score. I think its maybe because my question is vague but that's really the problem is that I don't know what direction to approach in but you've pointed me in the right one. I'll study this code now.

Comment: I think it's actually because you didn't include any of your own attempts or show enough effort. For next time...